# Limitations of MySQL JDBC

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jdbc, driver

Problem:

I get large ResultSet from DB(MySQL)(more than 1 000 000 rows) and handle each row about 40 seconds.
Summary, i work with ResultSet more than 30 minutes, i get less records than really contain in database table аnd have no errors and no warrnings. If i count quantity of rows of that ResultSet, it's allright(quantity of ResultSet = quantity of DB).

Is some limitations of mysql server or mysql jdbc driver or something else?

My code. it works in spring framework :

```
 public void query(String query, RowCallbackHandler rowCallbackHandler) throws SQLException {
    ResultSet rs = null;
    ResultSet rsCount = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    Statement stmtCount = null;
    try {
        stmt = createStatmant();

        rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

        if (rs == null) {
            log.info("result set is null");
        }

        stmtCount = createStatmant();
        rsCount = stmtCount.executeQuery(query);
        int i = 0;
        while(rsCount.next()){
            i++;
        }
        log.info("ResultSet size : "+i);

        int j = 0;
        rs.next();
        do{
            j++;
            rowCallbackHandler.processRow(rs);
        }while (rs.next());
        log.info("ResultSet size real : "+i);
        log.info("ResultSet size fact : "+j);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }finally{
        if(stmt!=null){
            stmt.close();
        }
        if(rs!=null){
            rs.close();
        }
        if(rsCount!=null){
            rsCount.close();
        }
    }
  }
```

createStatment :

```
  private Statement createStatmant() throws SQLException {

    ((BasicDataSource)dataSource).setTimeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis(1000*60*60);
    Statement stmt = dataSource.getConnection().createStatement(
            ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
    stmt.setFetchSize(fetchSize);
    stmt.setMaxRows(50000000-1);    
    return stmt;
}
```

datasource is global variable in class:

```
    private javax.sql.DataSource dataSource;
```

Comment: Paste your code please so its easy to identify the issue.

Comment: It looks like a problem in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're handing a mutable object, rs, back to your callbackHandler.  Make sure it's not advancing or closing the ResultSet.

You declare four objects that can be closed at the top of your method, but only close three at the bottom.  Don't forget to close stmtCount.

I'm assuming you're performing that count as a troubleshooting approach for our benefit, and that you're not doing that in production.

1 Million rows times 40 Seconds = 40 Million Seconds = 463 days.  The math doesn't support the statement that you "handle each row about 40 seconds".

Is anything externally writing to the database as you're reading?

If you're able to compare counts from your log, it means you haven't thrown an Exception.  That's a useful clue.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. yes there is some mistakes in my question and code. You aright think about time. 10 000 rows handled in 40 seconds.  i corrected code and delete many unnecessary things. It's didn't solution, but now it works fine.